# Searching for and displaying sql database data C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am new to coding and am currently doing some work with sql databases. I am supposed to create a database, display all the information in the database in a console application and then search for a specific "customerID" (One of the columns in the database) and display information regarding that customer.

I have been able to create the database and display the information, but I am not sure how I am supposed to display the data in my console application. I can display the top row information, but I can't figure out how to get to the lower rows. The information I have gotten from the one teaching me is not giving me enough to go on.

Please help!

```
SqlCeConnection con1 = new SqlCeConnection(conStr);
con1.Open();
SqlCeCommand cmd1 = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM shippingTable", con1);
SqlCeDataReader dr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

Console.WriteLine("Enter your customer ID (C1, C2 or C3");
string userValue = Console.ReadLine();

while (dr.Read())
{

    if (userValue == "C1")
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dr[1] + "Your product was shipped: " + dr[5]);
            break;
        }

    if (userValue == "C2")
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dr[1] + "Your product was shipped: " + dr[5]);
            break;
        }
    if (userValue == "C3")
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dr[1] + "Your product was shipped: " + dr[5]);
            break;
        }
    else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Something went wrong, you typed in the wrong customer ID");
            break;
        }
}
```

Comment: Please, clarify your indended behaviour. As I can see from your code - you are displaying exactly the same thing in all cases of user input. What is the reason of it?

Comment: Remove the `break;` s so you dont exit the read loop; (use an `else` or a `switch` - `break` does not jump from an `if`))

Comment: I wanted to check if the user input and the name for the specific CustomerID was the same, and then write out the results. These were some instructions I got from a tutor.

Answer (score 1):

You should be filtering the data at the database side using a where clause in your sql query.

`"SELECT * FROM shippingTable WHERE CustomerID = @CustomerID"`

Then when you set up the command, you will need to pass in the parameter and its value:

`cmd1.Parameters.Add("CustomerID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = userValue;`

This means you won't have to write code which searches through the possible values of customer IDs in the code - because what would you do if there were a million customers?

You could use `"SELECT * FROM shippingTable WHERE CustomerID = '" + userValue + "'"` but as @AndyKorneyev points out in the comments below this will leave your code open to injection attacks.

Likewise using `cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("CustomerID", userValue)` would be valid, but would run into conversion issues which would impact the application's performance - also pointed out by @AndyKorneyev with a good link to an article explaining the issue.

Consider something more like this:

```
        Console.Write( "Enter your customer ID: " );
        string userValue = Console.ReadLine(); // Get this before you even try and make a connection.

        using( SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection( conStr ) ) // using is used here because these objects implement IDisposable
        {
            con1.Open(); // Using will take care of closing the connection when it leaves scope.
            using( SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand( "SELECT * FROM shippingTable WHERE CustomerId = @CustomerId", con1 ) )
            {
                cmd1.Parameters.Add("CustomerID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = userValue;
                using( SqlDataReader dr = cmd1.ExecuteReader() )
                {
                    if( dr.Read() )
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine( dr[ 1 ] + " Your product was shipped: " + dr[ 5 ] );
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine( "Nothing was returned for Customer Id '" + userValue + "'" );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Don't teach OP the bad things. Concatenating sql query is straightforward way to SQL injection. Use parameterized queries instead.

Comment: A very true statement and OP should take note that parameters are better - I will update my answer.

Comment: much better, but still not ideal ;) Note that `AddWithValue` is terrible method and should be avoided if possible. Here is good article arguing this: http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: Haha! You learn something new every day. At least here you do. I will ammend again!

Comment: @Rob, could you put up the "bad code" that Andy refers to? Just make a note to not do ... it will serve as another learning point on this discussion. I think I understand but would like to see it ... thanks.

Comment: Since I am new to coding in general I was not entierly sure where to add the code you talk about. I added it before my while loop but got the error message "the name blah does not exist in the current context" So I declared myCustomerIdValue as a var earlier in the code. I had no idea if this is how you do things and now got the error No mapping exists from 'VarChar' to a known SqlDbType. Sorry for not getting it. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Hi @Nork - I changed the variable name back to one which matches your code sample and have provided a more complete answer with a sample of a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

The way to read data out of your database into your console application would be:

```
/* This approach will allow for parameters, avoiding Sql Injection.
   It also shows the 'TOP' for result, to limit the data your pulling.  The larger 
   the table, the slower the application. (Just example, tweak for real world.)
*/
string query = "SELECT TOP 50 * FROM [Database] WHERE ([Id] = @Id AND [Type] = @Type);";
using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbInConfig"].ConnectionString))
     using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
     {
          /*  The 'Using' will implement IDispose, which will save
              you resources, as once an item it out of scope will be 
              collected by Garbage Collection.
           */

           connection.Open(); // Self explanatory, open your database connection.

           // You can declare a parameter should you need one like this:
           command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", id);

          /* The downfall with 'AddWithValue' is it attempts to infer
             the database type, which can be wrong. */

          command.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = type;

          /* The generic add has you manually specifying the type,
             less room for error especially with big data.

          // Execute a Reader, to Read the data.
          using(SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
               while(reader.Read())
               {
                    // Within this scope, you can transmit data anyway you'd like.
                    if(reader["Column"] != DBNull.Value)
                         Console.WriteLine(reader["Column"].ToString());

                    /* You could populate a data model, or list to send 
                       to console in a tabular format.  Or do what I did
                       above which would show them one at a time. */
               }
     }
```

That should get you started working with a database, hopefully clarify a bit for you as well.  Use the `SqlDataReader` to read the data from your query back.  More information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader(v=vs.110).aspx).